# TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

after trying different possibilities, finally going to post:

This program will display an image to user. User will click on different regions of image using mouse click. On each mouse click, points are collected in list_of_points list. On right mouse click, I want to generate a polygon from list_of_points list. The library for polygon must be

> PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon(xy, fill=None, outline=None)

I am getting following errors repeatedly:

> TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

and this error:

> self.draw.draw_polygon(xy, ink, 0)
>   SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

coord=[]  # for saving coord of each click position
Dict_Polygon={}   # Dictionary for saving polygon
list_of_points=[]
flag=True
label=0

# Input image
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
def draw_lines(event):

    mouse_xy = (event.x, event.y)
    func_Draw_lines(mouse_xy)


def func_Draw_lines(mouse_xy):

    center_x, center_y = mouse_xy
    if canvas.old_coords:
            x1, y1 = canvas.old_coords
            canvas.create_line(center_x, center_y, x1, y1)

    # add clicked positions to list
    if flag==True:
        list_of_points.append(mouse_xy)
        canvas.old_coords = center_x, center_y

def draw_poly(event):

    numberofPoint=len(list_of_points)
    if numberofPoint>2:

        #draw =ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        poly=zip(list_of_points)
        print(poly)

        draw.polygon(poly, fill=None, outline=(255, 0, 0))
     #   label= canvas.create_polygon(list_of_points, fill='', outline='green', width=2)
        canvas.old_coords=None
        list_of_points[:]=[]

# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()    

# Draw canvas for iput image to pop up image for clicks
    filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas = Canvas(root,height=img.size[0],width=img.size[0])
    canvas.image = filename
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=filename)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.old_coords = None
# bind function to canvas to generate event
    canvas.bind("<Button 3>", draw_lines)
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>", draw_poly)
    root.mainloop()

`
```

Comment: You did a `print (poly)`, could we have the content of this variable?

Comment: zip(list_of_points) then values in poly are:  [((411, 113),), ((158, 169),), ((344, 364),)]

Comment: poly=tuple(list_of_points) the values in poly are: ((432, 224), (196, 245), (268, 379)) with no error but I no polygon is drawn.

Comment: @john the polygon is drawn on the PIL image, not on the `PhotoImage` displayed in the canvas, that's why we don't see it.

Comment: How to get it on PhotoImage for this specefic program where I am dealing with both canvas and PIL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a format like -

```
[(411, 113), (158, 169), (344, 364)]
```

But you are passing tuple of tuple-

```
((411, 113),), ((158, 169),), ((344, 364),)]
```

Try this structure -

```
[(432, 224), (196, 245), (268, 379)]
```

Or a straight list is also fine -

```
[432, 224, 196, 245, 268, 379]
```

Look at the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon)

Tuple of tuple becomes one argument for the function when it's expecting two. You don't need to `zip(poly)`, just passing `numberofPoint` should work. Let me know if that helps

Comment: When I print contents of list_of_points, I got the result: [[266, 126], [154, 238], [350, 266]], How to convert it to  this structure: [(432, 224), (196, 245), (268, 379)]

Comment: Something like this would do `[(i[0], i[1]) for i in x]`

Answer (score 0):

When I pass directly `list_of_points` to `draw.polygon`, it works fine, so no need of any conversion.

However, the polygon is drawn on the PIL image, not on the PhotoImage which is displayed in the canvas. Therefore, to see the polygon you need to update the PhotoImage. On way to d so is to use the `.paste` method of the `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

Here is the `draw_poly` function with the changes:

```
def draw_poly(event):
    numberofPoint = len(list_of_points)
    if numberofPoint>2:
        draw.polygon(list_of_points, outline=(255, 0, 0))  # replaced poly by list_of_points
        canvas.old_coords = None
        canvas.image.paste(img)   # update displayed image
        list_of_points[:]=[]
```